# How to prevent derived model from Single Table Inheritance in Rails 3.2.13 and how to convert inherited model object as derived model object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, single-table-inheritance

I've three models User, Group, Employee. Implemented Single Table Inheritance between User and Group model. But I don't want single table inheritance in Employee model which inherits User model but want to convert User model object as Employee model object. I achieved it by adding a piece of code, **self.inheritance_column = :_type_disabled** in Employee model and by calling the **becomes()** method on User object. It works in Rails 3.2.8 but not working in Rails 3.2.13 version.

**Exception is:**

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `_type_disabled=' for #<Employee:0xb429428>)
```

**Code snippet is:**

```
class Employee < User

  self.inheritance_column = :_type_disabled

  def self.current

    User.current.becomes(self)

  end

  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
 end
```

Please give me a solution to achieve this in Rails 3.2.13 too. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from my friend, we just need to define as virtual attribute in corresponding Model (In my case, Employee Model)

```
attr_accessor :_type_disabled
self.inheritance_column = :_type_disabled
```